# How to get these text output using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need this type of output. I already done with skew background but text is remaining, I need this type on text arrangement ?

[image]

but I get this instead:

```css
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3e3273;
  right: 25%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: skew(18deg, 0deg);
  padding: 15px 45px;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
  font-size: 35px;
  transform: skew(-18deg, 0deg);
  font-family: "MyriadPro-Regular";
  margin-top: 10%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-caption">
  <h3>Hey guys<br> please help me,<br> with this output</h3>

</div>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: hello this is my jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/bw63uevw/

Comment: Check out this link https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/

Comment: @ITbug I put the contents of your fiddle in a snippet in the question. That way, the question is self-contained.

Comment: Please merge your JS Fiddle into the question. Having the link additionally is fine, but if it is the only statement of what you have so far, the question is likely to be closed.

Comment: @shubham agrawal this is helpful I will do RND on it thank you :))

Comment: @MrLister thank you that was very helpful :))

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to not "de-slant" the h3 itself, but to put some block elements inside it and "de-slant" those. That way, they will be positioned correctly.
(Note that I used spans for the lines inside the h3, because using flow content such as divs would be an error according to the validator.)

```css
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3e3273;
  right: 25%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: skew(18deg, 0deg);
  padding: 15px 45px;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: "MyriadPro-Regular";
  margin-top: 10%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}

.carousel-caption h3 .line {
  transform: skew(-18deg, 0deg);
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-caption">
  <h3>
  <span class="line">Hey guys</span>
  <span class="line">please help me,</span>
  <span class="line">with this output</span>
  </h3>

</div>
```

Comment: this would be another way, probably a more reliable way than i mentioned. at first i tried using spans with staggered paddings, but it didn't seem to have an effect

Comment: any idea why using fixed paddings or margins didn't work on spans?

Comment: @Anthony Spans can have paddings, at least horizontally. Maybe there was something else that went wrong?

Comment: hm... well, the code was fine, though for some reason it wasn't being applied, which is why i didn't use that as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

simply use the no-break space (`&nbsp;`) like so...

```css
.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
   
    background-color: #3e3273;
    right: 25%;
    left: 10%;
    transform: skew(18deg, 0deg);
    padding: 15px 45px;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
    font-size: 35px;
    transform: skew(-18deg, 0deg);
    font-family: "MyriadPro-Regular";
    margin-top: 10%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Hey guys
            <br>&nbsp;please help me
            <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;with this output
            </h3>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bw63uevw/

Comment: This is by no means a guarantee that the slant will be the same.

Comment: @MrLister two no-break spaces will always be twice as long as one no-break space...

Comment: Yes, but a one nbsp indent per line will not necessarily produce an 18 degree angle!

Comment: @MrLister you're right, but i'm not sure that matters so much to the OP